# Best practice: Should multiple web-apps share one backend PHP file?

Tags: php, architecture

I have a few dozen single-page PHP apps running on a webserver, and currently they are all using the same backend .PHP file for their server calls.

Every time I am developing a new app or updating an existing one, I periodically and temporarily break the whole script, and therefore all apps, due to syntax errors, copy/pasting, etc.

Is this the "right" way to structure my site?

A pile of pages, each calling different functions in the same backend.php.

Interested in opinions if I should break my backend.php into one script per app, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems here (particularly putting untested code into production), but to answer your question: no, you should not have multiple apps in one file. A file should only contain one class or a group of related functions or other logic, not logic for multiple, unrelated apps.

Comment: I completely agree about production vs dev, but i was only given the one box. I'm keeping everything in GIT, as well as local copies (foo.php.working-as-of-25-feb-2016), but I hate it too.

I guess I'll split the backend up, it'll let me put the apps in separate repositories, which will be nice. Thanks for the advice.

In general, do you name the files something like "app-number-1.html" and "app-number-1.php"? Curious how you relate them. Or I suppose you could put each app in a separate folder? I'm learning as I go, and I'm sure you'd be horrified to watch me work!

Comment: @Clay only having one box has nothing to do with using one file for multiple apps. You can and should still separate unrelated logic into different files. Also, if you hate your version control system, you either (1) are using the wrong one for you or (2) more likely, are using it incorrectly. My VCS saves my tail multiple times a day, on a good day, and more than that on a bad one. That's true regardless of which one I happen to be using that day.

Comment: @Clay P.S. To the extent you mean that you can't set up a testing environment because you only have one box: nonsense. Look into Docker. You can set up as many as you like.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is cover the shared backend logic with unit tests. It also would mean, that you have to stop dumping everything in a one single flat file, but instead split up your code in classes.

To understand the basics of what unit testing is, you can start by watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w

I would also not that "single-page app" does not mean "single-file app". It would make you life a lot easier, if you separated the shared "framework" from the app-specific code.